# How to disable direct access to php file that streams an mp4

Tags: php, video-streaming

I have a php file that streams mp4 videos.

In my website I call the php file in the video tag src.

the php file is in a different server from website and its url is rewritten : server.xxxx.com/{id}

everything works perfectly but when I go on this link I can watch and download the video.

How can stop this from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the REFERER to the source page (like the video view page).

```php
# video.php
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=="https://video.com/watch"){
  echo "Forbidden";
  exit();
}
```

In the case where it doesn't matter you can also just check if the HTTP_REFERER header is set, otherwise fail.

```php
# video.php
if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
  echo "Forbidden";
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

I made a small change:

# video.php

<?php

if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],"https://video.com/watch") === FALSE) {
  echo "Forbidden";
  exit();
}